# Extract folder name from url in php

Tags: php

I am in a trouble that how i can extract folder name from url
Example - http://localhost/posts/author/FOLDER_NAME/live/?red=home 
I want to echo FOLDER_NAME to my webpage

```
<?php echo $name; ?>
```

Comment: see [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: you have to go with explode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do what you need, a simple one would be using [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$url = "http://localhost/posts/author/FOLDER_NAME/live/?red=home"
$folder = preg_replace('%.*author/(.*?)/live.*%', '$1', $url);
echo $folder ;
```

## Output:

```
FOLDER_NAME
```

---

## Update based on your comment:

```
$url = "http://localhost/posts/author/FOLDER_NAME?red=home"; 
$folder = preg_replace('%.*author/(.*?)\?.*%', '$1', $url);
echo $folder ;
```

## Output:

```
FOLDER_NAME
```

Comment: Now i am trying to use it like this - http://localhost/posts/author/FOLDER_NAME?red=home  Is this possible to remove ?red=home from url?

Answer (score 1):

You can explode the string by "/" and get the correct element like this:

```
print explode("/", "http://localhost/posts/author/FOLDER_NAME/live/?red=home")[5];
```

Comment: Get the correct element like what? You never demonstrate getting the correct element.

Comment: Yes he did. He is exploding the string, accessing the array at key 5.